# Resource controller rotue name inside a route group in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I have a resource controller placed inside a route group like so:

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
  Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index']);

  Route::patch('categories/{id}', ['uses' => 'controller@restore', 'as' => 'categories.restore']);
  Route::resource('categories', 'controller');
});
```

The first route is `admin/` with route name `admin.index` as expected.
The 'extra' resource route is `admin/categories/{id}` with route name `admin.categories.restore`.
But the strange things happen when we check the route names for the resource controller.
The routes are as expected, ed. `admin/categories/{categories}` but the route names are al prefixed with `admin.admin.`

I know I can fix the problem by removing the `as` in the route group and prefixing the route names for the other resources inside the group except the resource controller, but I'd like to find a way how to fix this without editing my route group.

The added image is (part of) my route lists
[image: route list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13903#issuecomment-230706965) comment on the laravel GitHub describes the issue perfectly.
What happend:
Pre [laravel-5.3](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.3), all resource controllers in a route group would first look for an `as` declaration, then for a `prefix` and would use both to define their name, e.g. `as.prefix.resource`.

[This](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14593) issue shows the clarification and changes made in Laravel 5.3 to prevent this behaviour. In its current form:

> URL prefixes no longer affect the route names assigned to routes when using Route::resource, since this behavior defeated the entire purpose of using route names in the first place.